# If column A's value is within the range of Column B and C then copy

Tags: excel, vba

in this project i have to check column's A value between Column B and Column C. If  columnA's values>= Columns B value or Columns A value<= Columns C value then i need to copy column d and e values and need to put into sheet1 column G and H. Column A is in sheet1 and Column B, C, D and E in sheet2.

I am sorry with my wordings i know its difficult to understand. If someone can help me with this i would be forever grateful. Thank you

```
             A       B    c   D     E
             1       1    9   Dog   Naruto
             11      10   19  Cat   one piece
             21      20   30  Duck  lo 



          i want the outcome like this
           A    G       H
           1    Dog     Naruto   
           11   cat     One piece
           21    duck     lo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do an if in each of the columns G and H.

In G1:

```
=IF(AND(A1<=C1,A1>=B1),D1,"")
```

And in H1:

```
=IF(AND(A1<=C1,A1>=B1),E1,"")
```

Or in H1 simply check if there is a value in G1 as:

```
=IF(G1<>"",E1,"")
```

Comment: i have to do it in vba brother thats the issue. I am new in vba

Comment: @GetSome_ in that case you need to show us how far you have come

Comment: i posted the code i it used for a different condition but kinda similiar. do you think you can tweak that code

Answer (score 0):

> this is the code i have but this code is for to check if Column A values = Column G values then it returns the whole row

```
              Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

            Set sht1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
           Set sht2 = Worksheets("sheet2")

             sht1= Worksheets("sheet1").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
             sht2= Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

           For j = 1 To sht1

                   For i = 1 To sht2

        If sht1.Cells(j, 7).Value = sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            sht1.Cells(j, 11).Resize(1, 2).Value = _
                          sht2.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value


        Else

        End If

    Next i

Next j

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

See below code (not tested).

```
Sub ColumnCheck()

Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim colA As Double, colB As Double, colC As Double

'assuming both sheets have the same amount of data rows
lRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'now loop
For i = 2 To lRow
    colA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    colB = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value
    colC = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value

    If colA >= colB Or colA <= colC Then
        'if true - set values
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & i).Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your effort however getting an error on the loop colA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value

Comment: Try it now. You were getting "Type mismatch error".

Comment: What row do your values start at? Note the for loop starts at row 2. Is this correct?

Comment: hey sorry to knock you again. What if the length of A column is greater than b and c column? i mean if there are 100 elements and duplicate values in A column how can i get  every value from c and d column for each value in A column ? hank you

Comment: @GetSome_ I am unsure I fully understand what you mean by the above

Comment: If A column has 400 rows and B and C column has 15 rows both.  and also A column has repetitive values  1, 6, 9 , 1 ,2 , 1 6, 2, 9 and so on.

Comment: Post an image of what you mean.